# Derivation of y(t)=H(s)x(t)

Tags: transfer-function, laplace-transform, system

\$x(t)=e^{st}\$ is the input to the system. \$x(t)\$ is not going to present in this question anything else than the exponential \$e^{st}\$ where t is time and s is a complex valued parameter.

\$H(s)\$ is the transfer function of the system.
\$y(t)\$ is the output of the system

$$ y(t)=x(t)*h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau) x(t-\tau) d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau) e^{st}e^{-s\tau}d\tau $$
$$ y(t) = e^{st}\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau) e^{-s\tau}d\tau = e^{st}\mathcal{L}\{h(\textbf{t})\} = x(\textbf{t})H(s).  $$

This is my derivation of the equation \$y(t)=H(s)x(t)\$. Is it correct?
if this derivation is correct, That means the overall response is \$H(s)x(t)\$. But according to my understanding, \$H(s)x(t)\$ only gives the forced response. The overall response should be calculated by inverse Laplace transform of \$H(s)X(s)\$. Where does this discrepancy come from? Thanks!

BTW, this is not derived by me,this derivation was done by [Professor
Ali Hajimiri](https://youtu.be/V-DKcohQEvg?t=247) at time 4:09

Comment: Use latex i.e. `\$x(t) = e^{st}\$` becomes \$x(t) = e^{st}\$ - reason - your handwriting is a scrawl.

Comment: Your input signal uses the symbol \$s\$, which also happens to be the name of the *frequency* domain variable used in Laplace transform. Now you have two variables with same name, but possibly different meanings. What would happen to the derivation if the input used a different symbol, say \$x(t) = e^{rt}\$ ?

Comment: To my knowledge, simplified expressions contain either the time variable (t) or the frequency variable (s). Both won't appear together. Either you are representing your signals & systems in time domain *or* in frequency domain, but not both. Expressions in frequency domain may contain specific time instances like \$t_0\$, but not t. Vice versa for time domain representations.

Comment: Alternately, why does the time domain representation of your input signal \$x(t)\$ depend on the frequency variable \$s\$ ? Can you plot \$x(t)\$ while allowing \$s\$ to hold any value value from \$-\infty\$ to \$+\infty\$ ? (i.e. you are not allowed to freeze the value of \$s\$ to any particular number).

Comment: For example,x(t)=e^(jwt),s=jw @AJN

Comment: This is a complex number input

Comment: Repeat your derivation with \$x(t) = e^{j\omega_0 t}\$ where \$\omega_0\$ is a *specific frequency* (say 5 rad/s) instead of being able to hold any value from \$-\infty\$ to \$+\infty\$. You may be confusing a signal having a *specific* complex frequency \$s_0 = \sigma_0 + j\omega_0\$ with the frequency *variable* \$s\$. Think about how you would plot the signal.

Comment: Then it would simply become y(t)=x(t)H(5). Where is the problem?

Comment: Is there any problem if I derive in such a way that s is variable instead of fixed value? The result should apply for any frequency

Comment: *Then it would simply become y(t)=x(t)H(5 j)*. This is correct. H(5 j) is the gain of the system for a sinusoidal input with frequency 5 rad/s. but it is better represented with a seperate symbol like \$x(t) = e^{s_0 t}\$ to avoid confusion while deriving.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110156/discussion-between-ajn-and-xiutao).

Comment: When doing a Laplace transform of a sinusoid or a complex sinusoid, you should use w (omega) for the frequency. This allows you to not confuse it with the general complex variable used in Laplace transform and also because the sinusoid is usually at some actual frequency  w. Thus use x(t)=e^(jwt). Then you can solve. Note you could also replace it with a complex variable a + jw also.

Comment: What if I let s=a+jw. I mean, s is a variable, a+jw is also variable. Why can't they be replaced with each other?

Comment: *y(t)=H(s)x(t)* can be better written as \$y(t)=H(s_0)x(t, s_0)\$ where \$x(t, s_0)\$ is a sinusoid of frequency \$s_0\$. This matches with the frequency response view of transfer functions. Writing *y(t)=H(s)x(t)* is like writing an equation where units do not match.

Comment: Sorry, I have just noticed that there is a typo. I have corrected it

Comment: Also note that, in the video you have linked, he seems to be using a two-sided Laplace transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform). It may *not* converge for a sinusoid input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have finally understood.
This derivation is correct except that the laplace transform of the impulse response is **not** the transfer function.
And when doing the laplace transform the upper limit should be negative infinity and the lower bound should be t.

**So basically, this derivation shows that the response of a system can be obtained by multiplying input x(t) and the laplace transform of the impulse response of the system with the upper bound going into negative infinity and the lower bound being t.**

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you're pretending that '\$s\$' is a run of the mill, real valued parameter, and then later in the analysis you say, oh no! it's really the Laplace operator. This means that your very first equation is mixing the time domain and the Laplace domain in the same expression, \$e^{st}\$, which is not valid.

Your analysis is not an accurate version of the youtube video, which actually shows that convolution in the time domain is equivalent to multiplication in the Laplace domain.

Comment: No, it is not a real valued parameter, it is intended to be a complex input

Comment: For example, v(t)=e^(jwt)

Comment: exactly, i don't see any problem

Comment: So \$x(t)= cos\:\omega t+jsin\:\omega t\$? A real signal cannot be a complex function of time.

Comment: It can. If not, why transfer function is H(jw)?

Comment: \$H(j\omega)\$ is frequency domain, not time domain.

Comment: In modulation and detection systems we have daily complex signals which have separate real and imaginary parts. They can be even separate voltages, not only numbers in a digital signal processor. One voltage is the real part and another is the imaginary part.

Comment: Please refer to phasor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#:~:text=In%20physics%20and%20engineering%2C%20a,%CE%B8)%20are%20time%2Dinvariant.

Comment: Phasors can be used in math but I have had in my hands analog circuits where real and imaginary parts of ONE signal were 2 separate voltages. It was in a radar.